Gospel of Thomas Log.13 - three words in Coptic or Greek or something else?
Referring to the (non-canonical/tertiary) Gospel of Thomas Log 13.6 (or 83.8):-
He spoke three words to him. (Brill, 1959).
https://www.gospel-thomas.net/keywords/Lnn_all.htm#L013
The word for words is šaje, which can be words or sayings
https://archive.org/details/copticdictionary0000crum/page/612/mode/2up
================================================
From free/online commentaries at earlychristianwritings.com:-
Marvin Meyer writes: "These three sayings or words are unknown, but presumably they are powerful and provocative sayings, since stoning (mentioned by Thomas) was the Jewish punishment for blasphemy.
1992
https://archive.org/details/gospelofthomashi0000unse
This is too recent to be public domain
== == == == ==
R. McL. Wilson writes: About the three words we can only speculate, but they were evidently blasphemous to Jewish ears. Puech suggests that they were the names 'Father, Son, and Holy Spirit,' Grant and Freedman the three secret words of the Naassenes (Hippol., Ref. 5.8.5).
1959
https://archive.org/details/neutestamentlich0001henn/page/206/mode/2up
H.-Ch. Purecu, Das Thomas-Evangelium, in E. Hennecke-W. Schneemelcher, Neutestamentliche Apokryphen’, t. I, ‘Tubingen, 1959, pp. 199-223.
I can't read German at all and since it's a loan item it isn't OCR'd
== == == == ==
F. F. Bruce writes: As for the three words spoken secretly to Thomas, conveying Jesus's hidden identity, they are probably the three secret words on which, according to the Naassenes, the existence of the world depended: Kaulakau, Saulasau, Zeesar.
1960
www.biblicalstudies.gospelstudies.org.uk › pdf › ft › gospel-of-thomas_bruce.pdf
"One of the Gnostic sects, the Naassenes, believed stones to be animate beings, and held that the existence of the world depended on three secret words―Canlacau, Saulasau, Zeesar.9 These words certainly convey an impression of mystery, until one realises that they are simply corruptions of the Hebrew phrases in Isaiah xxviii. 10, 13, translated ‘line upon line’, ‘precept upon precept’, and ‘here a little’! And it is probably more than a mere coincidence that Hippolytus refers to a Gospel of Thomas which he says was used by the Naassenes."
================================================
My question is would their workings be anywhere; basically whether the three words/sayings were Coptic or Greek (or some dialect of the Naassenes); and whether more recent archaeological findings have affected this
==
Izzit θεός // "I'll have an א‎ please, Bob"
Ἐγὼ ὁ θεός (Isaiah 45:21) would be three words, one of which gets the stoning.
It would complete a progression with the other two Greek loanwords
ἄγγελος > φιλόσοφος > θεός
And it might fit with GoT's apparent non-usage of a word for God, if that prohibition might have been in their minds
There is only Log 100 which has poute for the sentiment of 'give unto god that which is god's' but it's not clear the word poute refers to God. In the lexicon that's a primary meaning but it had a broader range including spirits/demons ("[Grant and Freedman]'s inference that Thomas may be reserving the name 'God' for use as that of an inferior power is also probably correct"). That might have Log 100 fitting a same conception of ἄγγελος > φιλόσοφος > θεός as Log 13, i.e. if poute(mere spirits) are below Caesar (humans) are below Jesus (God). For the possibility of ancient debate about where angels stand in relation to humans: Hebrews 1:1-14.
"God" remains a conjecture. Does the presence of a categorization-into-three in both Log 13 and Log 100 work for other words?
(30)   ἄγγελος | φιλόσοφος | Jesus (under another description)
(100)  kaisar | poute | Jesus
==
poute: https://archive.org/details/copticdictionary0000crum/page/230/mode/2up
==
Do they know and refer to Isaiah
Obviously Bruce holds they do
I am God isn't confined to Isaiah, but it's the OT text that most uses it: ~40 times. Brill lists an Isaiah echo for Log 32 to Isaiah 2:2 which seems to work at both verbal and theological levels. Alternatively Log 13 echoes Matthew 16:13-16 'people say he is Elijah or Jeremiah' and there is Log 39 > Luke 11.52 > Jeremiah 27 "ἔσομαι ὑμῖν εἰς θεὸν". (They know Luke but don't follow him in removing Jeremiah from Luke 9:8 [as audience-obscure?]).
It's not safe to assume they had the same books as the apostles, or that they followed them back to OT sources as we do aided by concordances and hyperlinks. At least "I AM" is an easy takeaway from Isaiah. Or from the apostle John; that he only uses 2 words isn't a reason to discount him.
Only two other echoes in Brill: Log 78 > Isaiah 24:21 (faint/bracketed) and Log 111 > Isaiah 34:4.

it's very difficult to see the specific question here, you did a good amount of research but could you please make it clearer what you're asking?

sorry I'm struggling with the SE format and I'm conscious it's better for me if those I'm asking can re-frame the question to what they have to teach. I'm asking what language the three words in the logion were in. Also (implicitly) whether structural parallels stand as a tool? Also whether there is a connection to Hebrews 1-14 or patristics. It is really a lot I am grateful for anything people have time to give me

I have tried to look at the specific text in my copy of the gospel of Thomas but cannot find the section to which you refer.  When I open your internet links, it does not reveal the text of anything but only provides a brief view.  Please find a text somewhere else and reference it so we know what we are supposed to be discussing.  Is this any help?  http://www.gnosis.org/naghamm/gosthom.html

or thus?  http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/shows/religion/maps/primary/gthomas.html

@Dottard, thanks have added a link above. Some versions have "three sayings" not "three words" which may thwart searches. [humour] which is of course a safety precaution in case of stonings leading to flamings [/humour]
